# Convert a multi page Tiff to jpeg in .Net1.1

Tags: .net, vb.net, jpeg, .net-1.1, tiff

Is there a way to convert a multi page Tiff file to a jpeg file in VB.net 1.1. I've tried to convert it with the standard Bitmap.Save() method but it only converts the first page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150405144620/http://bobpowell.net/addframes.aspx) for an example of this.

Basically you have to load the TIFF and paint the pages to new bitmaps in memory.